# RestKit build error: ../NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.h:19: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject'

Tags: xcode, xcode4, restkit

I've linked RestKit in an xcode 4 project, as described on the GitHub install page and am getting this error while trying to build. Does anyone know what is going on? I've asked on the RestKit IRC channel as well, and am waiting for an answer.

The error details are:

```
/Users/shyam/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/APXClient-bkpszicuinqyocawpsueiuiysrsk/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/include/RestKit/CoreData/NSManagedObject+ActiveRecord.h:19: error: cannot find interface declaration for 'NSManagedObject'
```

The install steps I followed are here:
https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/blob/master/README.md

Comment: After talking with blake on the RestKit IRC channel, this appeared to be an issue with recursive header include directories. In my case, I had `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/**` (recursive) in my header include paths. Making that non-recursive solved the problem.

Comment: I also ran into this issue and resolved it by making the Header Search Path non-recursive.  You should answer your own question :-)

Comment: done. thanks for confirming that recursive includes was actually the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, yes the solution is to make the header includes non-recursive. See details above

Comment: Can't find a build setting for setting header search paths to recursive/non-recursive. Please can you point me in the right direction.

Comment: A recursive pattern would look like `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/**` (note the `/**` suffix).

Comment: right. you replace /** with a path to a specific directory. For example, `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/some/lib`